# What are "torrents" in relation to gaming?

Tags: terminology

I see torrents mentioned on a lot of gaming sites. When I google it I get "strong and fast-moving stream of water or other liquid" -- what does it mean in relation to gaming?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Evorlor "this question does not show research effort" would be my guess.

Comment: I guess they wanted more details about fast moving liquids.

Comment: What about a torrent of abuse?

Comment: I think this question does show research effort.  I can only think of torrents as in the download method.    can you give us an idea of where you read this?

Comment: @Jcraft153 [https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Atorrent](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Atorrent)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Torrent actually refers to a peer-to-peer file transfer protocol called BitTorrent.

[image: P2P BitTorrent traffic]

This gif and more information can be found on [its Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent)

The idea is that once data gets *out there*, it can be distributed amongst the consumers. Because this can happen, it is often used for "illegal" download of media such as video games, movies, TV shows, and software, but can definitely be used legally.

Some examples of the usage of BitTorrent to download games (legally) is:

- Wargaming's World of Tanks and World of Warplanes launchers
- Blizzard's Battle.net downloader/launcher
- EVE Online's launcher
- Humble Bundle torrent download

Note that the launchers themselves do all the work—no need to get a client for them to operate properly.

If you are going to get a BitTorrent client, I would recommend Deluge or qBitTorrent, as they are open-source and do not include ads, which μBitTorrent and other clients do.

Comment: Great answer, I appreciate the inclusion of publishers who use torrents for legitimate distribution. I'd also note that the Humble Bundle store offers torrents as an option for downloading DRM-free games that one has purchased.

Answer (score -6):

A torrent is not "strong and fast moving liquid" I have absolutely no idea how you got that anwser. Anyways, a torrent is a peer to peer transfer.

If you go to the www.thepiratebay.se/ "Note this website can contain harmful viruses") This is a good example of a torrent downloading site.

Torrents (most likely) are used for illegal purposes as in the website I gave you earlier. They have free games that world have costed hundreds! They also have illegal videos, movies, and software. Some have used torrents as a money avoiding process.

Here www.wiki.vuze.com/Legal_torrent_sites is a website of legal torrents

Otherwise torrent are sometimes how developers would send you their contents(installer). There are also a good way to send big files. There are many software for this case such as frostwire.

Back to your original question, in relation to gaming would be a game download. A game installer with its files. Or illegally getting paid games for free.

Comment: You seem to think you have links in here, but there aren't any actual links here.

Comment: **-1** | It's not that you've linked to an illegal source, it's that it's poorly written, and your ideas are clear *but* fragmented (and doesn't add anything new).

Comment: [https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Atorrent](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Atorrent)