# A Minecraft PE mod is asking me if my device is 'rooted'. What does this mean?

Tags: mods, minecraft-bedrock-edition, terminology

I was trying to download the *Minecraft Alive* mod on Blocklauncher Pro but it keeps asking "Is your Kindle rooted?" and I have no idea what that means.

What does “rooted” mean, and how do I do it?

Comment: Voting to reopen as per: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11358/28182

Comment: @Timelord64 - rooting may also be needed in order to run certain emulators (less so these days but more common a few years ago). And this question gives another clear example of a legitimate use in the context of gaming (modding Minecraft PE), so I don't get why you're alleging that it should be unsupported here based on the fact that it *might* be used for "illegal things". The point of the meta establishes that if a term is used in the context of a game then it's on topic.

Comment: That meta was also the catalyst for [this one on torrents](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258443/what-are-torrents-in-relation-to-gaming) to remain open. If *that* is staying, so should this one.

Comment: Rooting is Jailbreaking google it. VERY KNOWN THING

Answer (score 4):

Rooting a device involves modifying it to edit files that you shouldn't be able to, such as the operating system. This is often a violation of the user agreement, will void your warranty, and shouldn't be done if you don't know what you're doing.

Suffice to say, if something is asking you if your device is rooted, the answer is "No". You'd know if it was.

Comment: [More info](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean)